# How to transform transfer functions into differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

is there a way with Mathematica to transform transferfunctions (Laplace) into differential equations?

Let's say I have the transfer function $\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\text{Kp} \left(\frac{1}{s \text{Tn}}+1\right)$.
What I want to get is $\dot{y}(t)\text{Tn}=\text{Kp}(\dot{u}(t)\text{Tn}+u(t))$.

On (I think) [Nasser's page](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL2/index.htm#x1-13600070) I found something I adapted:

```
sys = Kp (1 + 1/(Tn s))
sys = Together[sys]
rhs = Numerator[sys]
lhs = Denominator[sys]
rhs = rhs /. m_. s^n_. -> m Derivative[n][u[t]]
lhs = lhs /. m_. s^n_. -> m Derivative[n][y[t]]

eq = lhs == rhs
```

But this gives a wrong output for factors with $s^0$:

```
Input: eq

Output: Tn y[t]'==Kp (1+Tn u[t]')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm**

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[
  Array[(s + Subscript[a, ##])/(s + Subscript[b, ##]) &, {3, 2}], s]
```

> [image]

```
res = Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm[tfm];
```

The first argument has the differential equations

```
res[[1, 1]]
```

> [image]

and the output equations

```
res[[1, 2]]
```

> [image]

The second argument has the state variables

```
res[[2]]
```

> [image]

The third the input variables

```
res[[3]]
```

> [image]

The fourth the output variables

```
res[[4]]
```

> [image]

And the fifth the time variable

```
res[[5]]
```

> [image]

The function also works for delay systems

```
Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm[TransferFunctionModel[(Exp[-s T] s)/(s + 1), s]]
```

> [image]

```
Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm[
 TransferFunctionModel[{{{Subscript[\[SystemsModelDelay], 3] - 1}}, s + 3}, s]]
```

> [image]

For discrete-time systems it returns difference equations

```
Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm[
TransferFunctionModel[(z - 0.1)/(z + 0.6), z, SamplingPeriod -> 1]]
```

> [image]

**Legacy answer**

A solution for scalar transfer functions with delays.

The main function accepts the numerator and denominator of the transfer function.

```
tfmToTimeDomain[{num_, den_}, ipvar_, opvar_, s_, t_] := 
    Catch[polyToTimeDomain[den, opvar, s, t] == polyToTimeDomain[num, ipvar, s, t]]
```

A function to extract the numerator and denominator:

```
tfmToTimeDomain[tf_, rest__] := With[{tf1 = Together@tf}, 
    tfmToTimeDomain[Switch[Head@tf1, Times, {DeleteCases[tf1, Power[_, _?Negative]], 
    1/DeleteCases[tf1, Except[Power[_, _?Negative]]]} // Expand, 
    _, {Numerator@tf1, Denominator@tf1}], rest]]
```

Supporting functions:

```
polyToTimeDomain[poly_, var_, s_, t_] := With[{cl = CoefficientList[poly, s]},
    Plus @@ MapIndexed[coeffToTimeDomain[##, var, s, t] &, cl]]

coeffToTimeDomain[coeff_, {i_}, var_, s_, t_] /; FreeQ[coeff, Exp[__]] := 
    coeff Derivative[i-1][var][t]
coeffToTimeDomain[coeff_, {i_}, var_, s_, t_] := 
    coeff /. Exp[expr_] :> expToTimeDomain[expr, {i}, var, s, t]

expToTimeDomain[expr_, {i_}, var_, s_, t_] := Block[{cl}, 
     Switch[Length[cl = CoefficientList[expr, s]], 
        1, Exp[cl[[1]]] var[t], 
        2, Exp[cl[[1]]] Derivative[i - 1][var][t + cl[[2]]], 
        _, Throw[$Failed]
     ]
 ]
```

Examples:

```
tfmToTimeDomain[{Kp (s Tn + 1), s Tn}, u, y, s, t]
```

> [image]

```
tfmToTimeDomain[{Kp Exp[-s T1], s }, u, y, s, t]
```

> [image]

```
tfmToTimeDomain[{Kp Exp[-s T1] (s Tn + 1), s Tn}, u, y, s, t]
```

> [image]

The function should work for any continuous-time scalar transfer function with or without delays.

Comment: Wow, with Together[] this seems to be a very short and elegant way. I'll try it with some other transfer functions.

Comment: What about transfer functions with a time delay? Like $tf=\frac {\text {Kp}~e^{-s\text {T1}}} {s}$. Any idea how to handle these?

Comment: I have updated the function to handle delays as well. The cases I have not considered are discrete-time systems and multivariable systems.

Comment: Works great! Unfortunately for me it's not possible to select numerator and denominator  manually. But Numerator[]/Denominator[] treat the $e^{-s\text{Tt}}$ as Denominator. I tried to select them with %[[1]], %[[2]] ... but it does not work if i don't know how many factor are in the Numerator.

Comment: doesn't work for delayed integrative systems, too. Mix up your tow examples: $\frac{\text{Kp} e^{-s \text{T1}} (s \text{Tn}+1)}{s \text{Tn}}$

Comment: Updated again. My bad, I was thinking incorrectly about it and passed it to failed. Fixed now.

Comment: Phab, I have now added the function to extract numerators and denominators as well. Am I hand-holding too much. Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Just perfect! Can't find any example not working!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it addressed all you needed out of it. The functionality could probably be improved, but I will leave that for another time. And thanks for bringing up the original question.

Comment: I was wondering, Mma by itself didn't have such a function although there is a control systems environment with transferfunctions and Laplace transformations etc.  ... they should grab your function for next Mma release!

Comment: @SubaThomas Do you mind if I use your code in my work and when working on publications? Or maybe you have some kind of publication that I can refer to, and where did you use this algorithm?

Comment: @dtn you can use this code in your work. System` functions have a 'Cite this as' feature at the very end ([example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionModel.html#Citations)). Since this is kind of an internal feature so far, just point to this post.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

Here's a step-by-step albeit long-winded approach to deconstructing and reconstructing your differential equation. While not elegant, perhaps it provides alternatives or ideas for further development.

```
sys = Kp (1 + 1/(Tn s))
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[{{sys}}, s]
ssm = StateSpaceModel[tfm]
```

Extract the elements of the StateSpaceModel (the a, b, c, and d matrices):

```
sseqn = Take[Flatten[ssm[[1]], 2], 2]    (*  {0, 1}  *)
outputeqn = Drop[Flatten[ssm[[1]], 2], 2]    (*  {Kp/Tn, Kp}  *)
```

Construct the state-space equation:

```
xaccent = sseqn.{x[t], u[t]}    (*  u[t]  *)
```

and the output equation:

```
yaccent = outputeqn.{x[t], u[t]}    (*  Kp u[t] + (Kp x[t])/Tn  *)
```

Now in the output equation, substitute for the `x[t]` with the integral of the state-space equation:

```
yaccent /. x[t] -> Integrate[xaccent, t]
```

Then differentiate that w.r.t. `t` and set it equal to `y'[t]`:

```
D[%, t]
eqFinal = % == y'[t]
```

which gives:

[image]